# How to give the ant release parameters so it won't add debug symbols

Tags: android, ant, release, debug-symbols

I'm building an android app and i'm using ant to build it.
I wanted to know how can i give the ant release command parameters so it won't add any debug symbols / line numbers / local vars to the compiled unit.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though it was just including the word release or -r ?

Anyway maybe this links contents will help if it's more complex than that [Ant Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218452/detecting-build-configuration-debug-or-release-within-ant-script)